# Can't get Adwhirl to display ads - sum of ration weights is 0

Tags: android, admob, adwhirl

I'm trying to integrate adwhirl into my apps and have been having a very difficult time. Right now I am just using admob (which I could get working without adwhirl). I implemented the code following [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898838/howto-implement-adwhirl-in-an-android-project). I had originally tried using millenial media too, but was having the same errors. Below is my logcat. How can I fix this?

```
    E/AdWhirl SDK(  345): Unable to parse response from JSON. This may or may not be
 fatal.
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345): org.json.JSONException: Value [] of type org.json.JSONArra
y cannot be converted to JSONObject
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:107)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlManager.parseConfigurationString(A
dWhirlManager.java:288)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlManager.fetchConfig(AdWhirlManager
.java:255)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout$InitRunnable.run(AdWhirlLay
out.java:367)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(E
xecutors.java:444)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureT
ask.java:306)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:1
38)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$Sche
duledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:153)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$Sche
duledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:267)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Thr
eadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Th
readPoolExecutor.java:581)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
I/AdWhirl SDK(  345): Sum of ration weights is 0 - no ads to be shown
D/AdWhirl SDK(  345): Prefs{null}: {"config": "[]
D/AdWhirl SDK(  345): ", "timestamp": 1300240033837}
I/AdWhirl SDK(  345): Stored config info not present or expired, fetching fresh
data
D/dalvikvm(  345): GC_CONCURRENT freed 568K, 55% free 2799K/6151K, external 716K
/1038K, paused 5ms+4ms
D/AdWhirl SDK(  345): HTTP/1.1 200 OK
D/AdWhirl SDK(  345): Received jsonString: []
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345): Unable to parse response from JSON. This may or may not be
 fatal.
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345): org.json.JSONException: Value [] of type org.json.JSONArra
y cannot be converted to JSONObject
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:107)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlManager.parseConfigurationString(A
dWhirlManager.java:288)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlManager.fetchConfig(AdWhirlManager
.java:255)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout$InitRunnable.run(AdWhirlLay
out.java:367)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(E
xecutors.java:444)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureT
ask.java:306)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:1
38)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$Sche
duledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:153)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$Sche
duledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:267)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Thr
eadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Th
readPoolExecutor.java:581)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
I/AdWhirl SDK(  345): Sum of ration weights is 0 - no ads to be shown
D/AdWhirl SDK(  345): Prefs{null}: {"config": "[]
D/AdWhirl SDK(  345): ", "timestamp": 1300240334473}
I/AdWhirl SDK(  345): Using stored config data
D/AdWhirl SDK(  345): Received jsonString: []
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345): Unable to parse response from JSON. This may or may not be
 fatal.
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345): org.json.JSONException: Value [] of type org.json.JSONArra
y cannot be converted to JSONObject
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:107)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlManager.parseConfigurationString(A
dWhirlManager.java:288)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlManager.fetchConfig(AdWhirlManager
.java:255)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout$InitRunnable.run(AdWhirlLay
out.java:367)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(E
xecutors.java:444)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureT
ask.java:306)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:1
38)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$Sche
duledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:153)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$Sche
duledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:267)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Thr
eadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Th
readPoolExecutor.java:581)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
I/AdWhirl SDK(  345): Sum of ration weights is 0 - no ads to be shown
D/AdWhirl SDK(  345): Prefs{null}: {"config": "[]
D/AdWhirl SDK(  345): ", "timestamp": 1300240334473}
I/AdWhirl SDK(  345): Using stored config data
D/AdWhirl SDK(  345): Received jsonString: []
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345): Unable to parse response from JSON. This may or may not be
 fatal.
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345): org.json.JSONException: Value [] of type org.json.JSONArra
y cannot be converted to JSONObject
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:107)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlManager.parseConfigurationString(A
dWhirlManager.java:288)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlManager.fetchConfig(AdWhirlManager
.java:255)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout$InitRunnable.run(AdWhirlLay
out.java:367)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(E
xecutors.java:444)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureT
ask.java:306)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:1
38)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$Sche
duledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:153)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$Sche
duledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:267)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Thr
eadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Th
readPoolExecutor.java:581)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
I/AdWhirl SDK(  345): Sum of ration weights is 0 - no ads to be shown
D/AdWhirl SDK(  345): Prefs{null}: {"config": "[]
D/AdWhirl SDK(  345): ", "timestamp": 1300240334473}
I/AdWhirl SDK(  345): Using stored config data
D/AdWhirl SDK(  345): Received jsonString: []
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345): Unable to parse response from JSON. This may or may not be
 fatal.
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345): org.json.JSONException: Value [] of type org.json.JSONArra
y cannot be converted to JSONObject
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:107)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlManager.parseConfigurationString(A
dWhirlManager.java:288)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlManager.fetchConfig(AdWhirlManager
.java:255)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout$InitRunnable.run(AdWhirlLay
out.java:367)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(E
xecutors.java:444)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureT
ask.java:306)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:1
38)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$Sche
duledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:153)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$Sche
duledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:267)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Thr
eadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Th
readPoolExecutor.java:581)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
I/AdWhirl SDK(  345): Sum of ration weights is 0 - no ads to be shown
D/AdWhirl SDK(  345): Prefs{null}: {"config": "[]
D/AdWhirl SDK(  345): ", "timestamp": 1300240334473}
I/AdWhirl SDK(  345): Using stored config data
D/AdWhirl SDK(  345): Received jsonString: []
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345): Unable to parse response from JSON. This may or may not be
 fatal.
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345): org.json.JSONException: Value [] of type org.json.JSONArra
y cannot be converted to JSONObject
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:107)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlManager.parseConfigurationString(A
dWhirlManager.java:288)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlManager.fetchConfig(AdWhirlManager
.java:255)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout$InitRunnable.run(AdWhirlLay
out.java:367)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(E
xecutors.java:444)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureT
ask.java:306)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:1
38)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$Sche
duledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:153)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$Sche
duledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:267)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Thr
eadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Th
readPoolExecutor.java:581)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
I/AdWhirl SDK(  345): Sum of ration weights is 0 - no ads to be shown
D/dalvikvm(  345): GC_CONCURRENT freed 391K, 55% free 2808K/6151K, external 716K
/1038K, paused 4ms+4ms
D/AdWhirl SDK(  345): Prefs{null}: {"config": "[]
D/AdWhirl SDK(  345): ", "timestamp": 1300240334473}
I/AdWhirl SDK(  345): Using stored config data
D/AdWhirl SDK(  345): Received jsonString: []
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345): Unable to parse response from JSON. This may or may not be
 fatal.
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345): org.json.JSONException: Value [] of type org.json.JSONArra
y cannot be converted to JSONObject
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:107)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlManager.parseConfigurationString(A
dWhirlManager.java:288)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlManager.fetchConfig(AdWhirlManager
.java:255)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout$InitRunnable.run(AdWhirlLay
out.java:367)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(E
xecutors.java:444)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureT
ask.java:306)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:1
38)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$Sche
duledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:153)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$Sche
duledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:267)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Thr
eadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Th
readPoolExecutor.java:581)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
I/AdWhirl SDK(  345): Sum of ration weights is 0 - no ads to be shown
D/AdWhirl SDK(  345): Prefs{null}: {"config": "[]
D/AdWhirl SDK(  345): ", "timestamp": 1300240334473}
I/AdWhirl SDK(  345): Using stored config data
D/AdWhirl SDK(  345): Received jsonString: []
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345): Unable to parse response from JSON. This may or may not be
 fatal.
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345): org.json.JSONException: Value [] of type org.json.JSONArra
y cannot be converted to JSONObject
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:107)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlManager.parseConfigurationString(A
dWhirlManager.java:288)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlManager.fetchConfig(AdWhirlManager
.java:255)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout$InitRunnable.run(AdWhirlLay
out.java:367)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(E
xecutors.java:444)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureT
ask.java:306)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:1
38)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$Sche
duledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:153)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$Sche
duledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:267)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Thr
eadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Th
readPoolExecutor.java:581)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
I/AdWhirl SDK(  345): Sum of ration weights is 0 - no ads to be shown
D/AdWhirl SDK(  345): Prefs{null}: {"config": "[]
D/AdWhirl SDK(  345): ", "timestamp": 1300240334473}
I/AdWhirl SDK(  345): Using stored config data
D/AdWhirl SDK(  345): Received jsonString: []
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345): Unable to parse response from JSON. This may or may not be
 fatal.
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345): org.json.JSONException: Value [] of type org.json.JSONArra
y cannot be converted to JSONObject
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:107)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlManager.parseConfigurationString(A
dWhirlManager.java:288)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlManager.fetchConfig(AdWhirlManager
.java:255)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout$InitRunnable.run(AdWhirlLay
out.java:367)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(E
xecutors.java:444)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureT
ask.java:306)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:1
38)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$Sche
duledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:153)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$Sche
duledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:267)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Thr
eadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Th
readPoolExecutor.java:581)
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
I/AdWhirl SDK(  345): Sum of ration weights is 0 - no ads to be shown
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with no ad networks configured.  Adding a house ad fixed it for me.  Did you confirm that AdMob is turned on in the AdWhirl server control panel?

Answer (score -1):

For Android APplication, try uninstalling it and then re upload into your mobile.
It can help.